# how to connect oracle 9i database to forms 6i

Tags: database, oracle, sqlplus, oracleforms, oracle9i

I recently restored my old computer's system (running win XP SP2), on which I was using oracle 8i in addition to Forms and Reports 6i.

Unfortunately, restoring the system deleted the software, and thereafter I had no access to the local database nor the Forms and Reports I had earlier.

I then installed Oracle 9i v 9.0 as I think that Oracle DB usually has 2-updates compatibility. The installer didn't recognize my 8i database so I went on creating a new 9i database, but now I can't connect forms 6i.

Logging in to sqlplus 9 works fine, but sqlplus 8 requires

DATABASE CONNECTION (e.g. t:node:SID) [LOCAL]

What should the input be??

My 9i `SID = ABD` and `tnsnames.ora` is cloned from 9i network folder to 6i net80 folder.

Thank you in advance

Comment: XP SP2? Forms 6i? Oracle 8i? Are you running a museum of obsolete enterprise software?

Comment: lol i'm trying to retrieve data that I've saved long back.@APC

Comment: Forms 6i has its own Oracle_home
Oracle 9i has its own Oracle_home.
Versions of the libraries vary.
The priority of calling the libraries depends on the order in the PATH environment variable.
Show the file tnsnames.ora
run tnsping.exe in ORACLE_HOME forms6i

It is better to migrate the database to another computer or virtual machine.
Forms 6i works great with Oracle 11g.

Comment: Oracle client 11g can not connect to Oracle 9 and Oracle 8.
You will be shocked but oracle client 7.3 works fine with Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, 6i version should be installed in this order: database first, then Reports, and Forms at the end. Why? Because Reports installation overwrites Forms' configuration files, but Forms installation won't overwrite Reports' ones.

Apart from that, the rest should be relatively simple: if you don't use TNS_ADMIN environment variable (my suggestion: do use it), then you have to manually maintain all copies of TNSNAMES.ORA synchronized - that's what you already did: put copy into \developer_suite_home\network\admin directory.

Forms should then be able to recognize the database and connect to it.